# How to upload a file using php to the parent directory

Tags: php, file, forms, ftp, uploading

Hopefully easy question, I have a desktop application that allows the user to upload a file to a server using a form, the form sends the data to a protected file on the site like this. Site_root/protected_folder/myfile.php . If you use php file upload commands normally you'd be operating in the 'protected_folder' directory, which I don't want.

I want to add stuff to the images file on the root directory like this Site_root/images/ , how would you go about doing this without going the ftp root?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual method is to call [move_uploaded_file()](http://php.net/move_uploaded_file), where you set the destination path to your liking. The file name in [`$_FILES['tmp_name']`](http://es.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php) normally points to a temporary folder and it's subject to be removed without prior notice.

Answer (score 3):

You can either use an absolute path like `/path/to/images/` or use a relative path like `../images/`

Assuming you're using `move_uploaded_file` the second paramater takes the directory that you wish to upload to. Perhaps showing you code may help if this post doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

`move_uploaded_file()` *will* allow you to place uploads relative to the **root directory** if you simply start your path with a slash like

```
$newFileDir = '/username/public_html/websiteroot/subdir/yourfile.jpg';
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['postname']['tmp_name'],$newfileDir);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use copy() and double dot (../) in path to specify root directory to copy the uploaded file. I'm using the same. You may want to change the file name so that there will be unique filename in the directory error will occur. extension will also be same.
//

```
$filename = stripslashes($_FILES['postname']['name']);
$extension = getExtension($filename);
$newfilename ='photo_your_filename'.time().'.'.$extension;
$newFileDir = '../subdir/'.$newfilename;
copy($_FILES['postname']['tmp_name'],$newfileDir);
```